# how to use activity context from other activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to use activity context from another activity simple code example below Any idea ?

```
public class Activity_A extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_Activity_A);
}
}
```

---

```
public class Activity_B extends AppCompatActivity {
Dialog dialog1 ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_Activity_B);

dialog1 = new Dialog(I want Activity_A Context) ; // Is this possible ??

}
}
```

---

Thanks

Comment: why do you want the context of another activity, android specifically only has one active activity at a time. `Is this possible` probably, but you most definitely shouldn't be even attempting it

Comment: I'm a beginner in Android applications, so there is no way thanks again

Comment: actually why do you want to do that? We might help you to get what you want in the same activity.

Comment: i want to make custom download dialog and i will to use it like "new start_download(url)"  from any activity but I do not know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tamim you can definitely achieve this using a different class by making a public static function in that other class

```
public class Utils {

 public static void showDialog(Context context){
 //// your code here
 }
```

now you use it wherever you want...

```
Utils.showDialog(this);
```

Comment: Thanks it's working